# PyGame Error: RGBA Argument

Tags: python, pygame, rgba

I just started using PyGame and I'm trying to make a message show players when they lose, but I'm getting an error back.

```
red = (2555, 0, 0)
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])
```

--etc etc

```
message_to_screen("You Lose", red)
pygame.display.update()

time.sleep(2)
```

The exact error message is

```
 screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
 TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument
```

I can't find any answers online. Please help!

Comment: Each channel has a range of 0 to 255. 2555 is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your color definition:

```
red = (2555, 0, 0)
```

The possible values for each RGB channel can be in the range 0 to 256 (exclusive). This means 2555 is *waaay* to big. Pygame sees this and correctly raises an error. If you're trying to encode the RGB value of the color red, you need to use 255 not 2555:

```
red = (255, 0, 0)
```

As a side note, you may find something like an [RGB color selector](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-picker/) to be helpful while in the process of choosing colors for your game.